# Using media images in a template in Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco7

In previous versions before Umbraco 7, there was an image link on the Media properties tab of an uploaded image. If I remember correctly, you could use that to identify the image and use the upload "Overwrite" option to directly update and overwrite an image. This was useful to switching out an updated logo (or other site images) for the site Template without having to do a bunch of copy and paste.

Is there a easy way to do this in Umbraco 7?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the data type of the property to the media picker instead and then using the umbraco image item like below

```
<umbraco:Image field="articleImageOne" runat="server" />
```

where "articleImageOne" is the property alias. It will be better in managing images.

Answer (score 0):

I've only used Umbraco 7 and I can only speak for that version. What I always do is have a media picker for the logo and create it as a property of course. So, whenever I want to change it (or the editor or whoever), I just go and change the logo in the property and it instantly changes across the whole website. Same with every other image I need. Media Picker is my go to Editor and Image Cropper. Depends on what you use it for.

[Media Picker](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/media-picker)
[Image Cropper](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/getting-started/backoffice/property-editors/built-in-property-editors/image-cropper)

Answer (score 0):

The "Upload" datatype will store the URL of the uploaded file. The "Media Picker" datatype will store an ID of an item from the media library. If you plan to replace images but do not wish to make multiple template amends then I recommend using the media picker rather than the upload datatype. You can then use the Umbraco.TypedMedia(id) function to get the image and all it's related information on the fly.